# Masking values in SQL select return

Tags: mysql

This is an odd question, but I was wonder if you could display one column in the results, but really have another column as the values (MYSQL). Suppose I have this table:

```
ID   Name
1    Soccer
2    Football
```

I was wonder if it was possible to select all IDs from this table (select ID from table), but the results would display the name instead.

Or is it possible to display as the result (as a single column)?:

```
1 (Soccer)
2 (Football)
```

Comment: What?  You can select both columns `SELECT ID, Name FROM ...` or just select the `Name` column if that's all you want: `SELECT Name FROM ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT("(", name, ")") FROM <TABLENAME>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will have results concatenated into single column.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ID, ' (', Name, ')')
FROM tableName
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e9ea8/1)